# Using Tabbed Page with Master Detail page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using MasterDetail page in xamarin forms, my detail page is a tabbed page with three tabs, my problem is when I am writing below code in MasterDetail Page to remove NavigationBar from that page

```
        protected async override void OnAppearing ()
        {
            base.OnAppearing ();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this,false);

        }
```

Then my tab page is not working properly like all tabs got disabled.
But without using this code everything is working fine.
But I need to write this code as I don't want that navigation bar on my master detail page.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation bar by creating a new `NavigationPage(new YourTabbedPage)` and then you can use the code to hide the NavigationBar

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this,false);
```

You can have different NavigationPage MainPage of your App.cs you can have an instance of your App.cs like this:

public static `App Instance { get; private set; }`

So now you can set:

```
App.Instance.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YoutTabbedPage());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have done something like this for loading MasterDetail page and its working fine if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
       Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
       Application.Current.MainPage = new Root();
      }else{
       Application.Current.MainPage = new Root();
      }